# Split the results of a query into parts

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

I got this question in an exam, the teacher asked us to raise the employers' salaries using the following rules using a cursor:

- An extra 4% for the first quarter with the highest salary.
- An extra 6% for the second quarter with the highest salary.
- For the rest an extra 8%

How to approach solving this.

My attempt was `SELECT SALARY FROM (SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY SALARY) rownum > count(*)/4` to get the salary at first then add the %4  raise and update it to the new value.

I haven't tested it but I guess it might work, but I think it's a bit too far fetched and there may be a better or more efficient solution, your thought guys ?

Comment: A data sample (preferably in the form of a DDL/DML script) and the expected result go a long way in questions like this. Such an example helps a lot in clearing any doubts for someone who might find the verbal description not to be  entirely clear. As they say, [help us help you](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)! Other than that, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, I did the following:

Create table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE salesperson (id INTEGER, salary INTEGER);

INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (1, 100000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (2,  80000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (3,  60000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (4,  50000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (5,  30000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (6,  25000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (7,  12000);
INSERT INTO salesperson VALUES (8,  10000);
```

Then run this query (SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37b2aa/2)):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, salary, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY salary) AS quartile
  FROM salesperson
)   --     <<== you can do a SELECT * FROM cte to see what's happening!
SELECT
       id,
       salary,
       CASE quartile
         WHEN 1 THEN salary * 1.08
         WHEN 2 THEN salary * 1.08
         WHEN 3 THEN salary * 1.06 
         WHEN 4 THEN salary * 1.04
       END as new_salary
FROM cte;
```

Result:

```
ID  SALARY  NEW_SALARY
1   100000  104000
2   80000   83200
3   60000   63600
4   50000   53000
5   30000   32400
6   25000   27000
7   12000   12960
8   10000   10800
```

HTH and welcome to the forum! :-)

You can read the Oracle NTILE documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm) and an explanation from the **excellent** oracle-base site [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ntile-analytic-function).

EDIT:

You can also do it in one pass - but I think the cte (COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION - or WITH clause) shows the thought process more clearly. Thus:

```
SELECT
       id,
       salary,
       CASE NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY salary) 
         WHEN 1 THEN salary * 1.08
         WHEN 2 THEN salary * 1.08
         WHEN 3 THEN salary * 1.06 
         WHEN 4 THEN salary * 1.04
       END as new_salary
FROM salesperson
ORDER BY id;
```

Same result ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37b2aa/3))!

Answer (score 0):

> I meant the idea, not the literal implementation of the query

I'll write the idea too, well?

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY quarter ORDER BY salary DESC) rnk 
              FROM datatable )
UPDATE datatable
SET salary = salary * CASE WHEN rnk=1 AND quarter=1 THEN 1.04
                           WHEN rnk=1 AND quarter=2 THEN 1.06
                                                    ELSE 1.08 END
FROM cte
WHERE id = cte.id
```

Comment: Is PARTITION BY quarter part of Oracle ? And could you please elaborate on some points, I do not completely understand it.

Comment: @AbdessalemBoukil `quarter` in this scheme is the name of a field (if exists) or the placeholder for an expression which calculates the quarter from the date/timestamp.

Comment: I think by quarter the OP meant one fourth part of the number of employees. It's mainly a guess but it's supported by the OP's pseudo code (the `rownum > count(*)/4` part).

Comment: @AndriyM Maybe... this variant is solved in Vérace's answer.